# Installing Emscripten on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, emscripten

I am trying to install Emscripten on Ubuntu, but [the official installation guide for Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/Tutorial) doesn't offer any instructions for installing Emscripten on Linux. The only advice that the installation guide has to offer is:

`If you are on Linux, things should be very simple for you and there is no need for any additional guide.`

I have read the README.md file in the Emscripten repository as well, and it doesn't offer any instructions for Ubuntu either. What steps will I need to follow in order to set up Emscripten on Ubuntu?

Comment: Will I need to compile any of the source code in the Emscripten repository in order to use it, or is it pre-compiled somehow?

Comment: After installing all of Emscripten's dependencies, I simply ran `./emcc` in the Emscripten repository folder, and that seemed to work. It appears that no additional installation steps are required (correct me if I'm wrong.)

Comment: I'm still not sure how I should install LLVM and Clang on Ubuntu - the tutorial doesn't provide any details about this.

Comment: Here is an link which give a detail steps for Installing Emscripten on Ubuntu 12.10,
https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/Getting-Started-on-Ubuntu-12.10

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For getting started with *clang 3.2* I assume you are running *Ubuntu 12.10*.
*13.04* already has *clang 3.2* packaged, so I would recommend using these package(s).

There are two ways of getting them:

1. **Installing/Upgrading selected packages of Ubuntu 13.04 (minor intrusive)**

   - Add `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse` to your sources.
   - Update your package info (e.g. `sudo apt-get update`)
   - Install only the needed package and dependencies (e.g. `sudo apt-get install clang-3.2`)
   - Disable the source entry, added before.
2. **Upgrade/Install Ubuntu to 13.04+**

**EDIT:**

Update to current situation.

Comment: Will I need to install LLVM and Clang separately? If so, which version of LLVM will I need to install?

Comment: Installing _clang_ will automatically install the corresponding llvm.

Comment: @NoBugs I said _13.04 prelease_, which was buggy. _13.04 release_ is ok.

Comment: clang 3.3 and 3.4 are also available in the repository. Would it be better to go with the newest clang, or stick with 3.2 for emscripten?

Comment: @Bram Emscripten currently only works with 3.2. We hope that 3.4 gets supported the next month.

Answer (score 8):

For Ubuntu 12.04 it is also very easy.

1. go to http://llvm.org/releases/download.html and download LLVM 3.2 (Clang Binaries for Ubuntu-12.04/x86) LLVM is integrated
2. extract it to a place you like eg. `~/opt/dev/llvm`
3. add this to your .profile `PATH="$PATH:/home/[your_profile]/opt/dev/llvm/clang3.2/bin"`
4. make sure you have nodejs installed
5. follow the instructions for the emscripten installation

thats all

if you get `/usr/include/features.h:324:10: fatal error: 'bits/predefs.h' file not found`
simply install `sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-i386`

Comment: That's what you call easy? ;)

Comment: yes? What else should be easier than download and configure with one line? do you expect an installation script from me? if you can't follow simple 4 steps why do you wanna use something so complicated as emscripten?

Comment: @dustin.b “make sure you have nodejs installed”: why does it requires NodeJS? Acutally pre‑built Ubuntu binaries for LLVM 3.4.2, are only for 64 bits machines, nothing for 32 bits (I hope this does not mean there are issues with LLVM on Ubuntu 32 bits platforms). LLVM 3.4 still comes with 32 bits binaries.

Answer (score 3):

[Emscripten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emscripten) is a complex system  of software tools with support for multiple platforms.  As is typical for such systems, the getting-started instructions can be a bit cryptic.  A first sad note is that [just installing emscripten from the Ubuntu repos probably isn't your best bet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26445496/86967), at least for now.

I got much of what I needed by downloading [Portable Emscripten SDK for Linux and OS X](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/getting_started/downloads.html), and following these steps from the included README.md file:

- Run .`/emsdk update`. This will fetch the latest registry of available tools.
- Run `./emsdk install latest`. This will download and install the latest SDK tools.
- Run `./emsdk activate latest`. This will set up ~/.emscripten to point to the SDK.

Note that the initial download is tiny, but running the steps above takes a while (on the order of an hour, but probably depends on Internet speeds) and uses about 13G of disk space.

I found that I also needed to install (on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS):

```
apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

There may be other dependencies required, which will hopefully be easy to track down based on the error messages that you see.

Here's a simple example of how you might build and run a C++ program:

```
emsdk_portable/emscripten/tag-1.34.8/em++ hello.cpp -o temp.html
chromium-browser --new-window temp.html
```

Comment: I took an indirect route to getting this installed, it included first running `apt-get install emscripten`.  *This may have pulled in dependencies that I would have otherwise had to install separately*.  After I built with emsdk and noticed a little confusion about package locations, I used synaptic to remove clang and llvm components that didn't seem to be dependencies of anything else that I was using.