# Recommended environment for Emscripten full language compile

Tags: emscripten

I would like to compile a [C-based language](http://cran.r-project.org/) into javascript using Emscripten.
The documentation [here](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/Tutorial) and [here](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/Building-Projects) suggests that success rates are somewhat dependent on environment. Fortunately, With virtualization it's very easy to spin up whatever environment is needed for the job. Can anyone suggest what linux flavour would be the best choice for compiling a sizeable project? 
Any other related tips are welcome.

Comment: More than Environment, it is important that you know what you are doing. If you are fluent in _compiling_ / _advanced c_ / _javascript_ you should be fine on your prefered environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Ubuntu you can do all you want. For how can use take a look on [Installing Emscripten on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902514/installing-emscripten-on-ubuntu)