# emscripten issue with ubuntu version "aborting from js compiler due to exception: unknown vector type <4 x i8> | undefined"

Tags: c++, ubuntu, emscripten

I cannot compile anything with the current version of emscripten from the ubuntu repos

Here is the error

http://pastebin.com/j5Z0ztTs

I suspect it might be because emscripten is outdated in the repos, but why is there no bug reports??

Could anyone help? I cannot find any updated information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The version of emscripten (and/or its dependencies) in the Ubuntu 14.04 repository doesn't seem to work for C++ (might be OK for C though).  If you want to use C++, you probably will have to install emscripten and/or clang from a different source.  [Here's a specific question about how to do that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14902514/86967).

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because you are using the `/usr/bin/clang++` that comes with your Linux distribution.

This version does not support Javascript backend. In order to use emscripten, `you have to compile fastcomp` (an LLVM clang compiler with Javascript backend added)

If you have not built fastcomp yet, Emscripten won't work.

Check out this page for installation instructions:

http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/building_from_source/LLVM-Backend.html

---

If you have already built fastcomp, then the problem is in your `emscriptenrc` file, and moreover your PATH.

This is how I worked around the issue:

I created a file called emscriptenrc.sh  that did this:

```
export PATH=/home/mike/emscripten/fastcomp/build/master/bin:/home/mike/emscripten/fastcomp/build/master/include:/home/mike/emscripten/fastcomp/build/master/lib:$PATH
```

then after I created that file

I rebuilt the `~/.emscripten` configuration file by calling

`./emcc -v`  from the emscripten build directory -- this seemed to get the right version of clang registered...

now you can go ahead and compile with emcc

I would suggest reading http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/building_from_source/LLVM-Backend.html
as well as the rest of the documentation prior to trying to use emscripten.